# Not able to get popup in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have created one module where I added one extra step in the checkout after payment. In that step I added one varchar field and putting data manually. Also I have created same field in sales_flat_order and sales_flat_quote. Now I am trying to get popup for that field to check duplicate value. For that I overwrite two files OnepageController.php in controllers folder and Onepage.php in Model folder and trying to create a popup, But I am not able to get a popup in it. It stays at the same step, but popup does not comming out.

I have used this [link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step?facebook=1) to add step in the checkout.

Comment: Did you change the template also?

Comment: Yes I created .phtml file